# qhull library is not loaded in python

Tags: python-2.7, qhull

I recently installed a package that only runs with python2.7. Within this package, `qhull` is imported by

```
import matplotlib._qhull as _qhull
```

which leads to getting this error

```
ImportError:dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libqhull.8.0.dylib  

Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.so
```

Reason: image not found

I have reinstalled `qhull` by brew, but I still get the above error. I have checked `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/` and `_qhull.so*` was there.

I have checked `brew doctor` and didn't get any complaint regarding `qhull`. Library `qhull` can be found in `/opt/local/lib/` on my system. I also run

```
python2.7 -m pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

to make sure that my matplotlib is upgraded.

As I mainly work with Python3, I would look for a solution that does not cause any changes to my python3 configuration. Do you have any suggestions on solving this problem?